# Can Silvery Barbs and Voice of Authority be used together?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, cleric

When casting [Silvery Barbs](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silvery-barbs), could one apply the Order Domain class feature Voice of Authority to the second half of the spell?

Comment: I’ve added the D&D 5e tag since you mentioned several 5e features (silvery barbs, order domain, voice of authority). Welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment.

Comment: Somewhat related, especially because of the timing aspect : https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/181871/77044

Answer (score 10):

#### Yes, this works.

Voice of Authority states:

> If you cast a spell with a spell slot of 1st level or higher and target an ally with the spell, that ally can use their reaction immediately after the spell to make one weapon attack against a creature of your choice that you can see.

*Silvery barbs* is a 1st level spell, and says:

> You can then choose a different creature you can see within range (you can choose yourself). The chosen creature has advantage on the next attack roll, ability check, or saving throw it makes within 1 minute.

If you select an ally for this part of the spell, you have met all the requirements for using Voice of Authority (cast a 1st level spell, target an ally), and your ally may immediately use their reaction to make one weapon attack *with advantage*. The attack is with advantage because Voice of Authority states that the reaction happens *after* the spell.

Comment: My reading is that the target of the spell Silvery barbs is the enemy creature, rather than the ally. The ally is merely _affected_ by the spell, but they are not the _target_ of the spell. Or maybe I'm too pedantic?

Comment: @MooingDuck Targeting is woefully underdefined in 5e. But you are choosing an allied creature to affect with the spell, I don't see how you could say that isn't targeting them with the spell.

Comment: @MooingDuck And I argue in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/180665/62294) that even creatures affected by simple area of effect spells are targets of such spells.

Comment: Both of these interpretations match my reasoning when reading the wording as well... guess it'll be up to the DM. Thanks folks